# Best CSS and JS aggregation/minification strategy for D7

Tags: 7, theming, performance, css-js-aggregation

Drupal 6 has the awesome [advagg](http://drupal.org/project/advagg) module, which does an awesome job of *intelligently* bundling CSS and JS, but currently no D7 release.

What I am looking to achieve is:

- less CSS and JS files (5 CSS and 5 JS files is far too many)
- JS files have minification (currently core only does this for CSS)

Is there a drupal 7 solution that will help here? What are other people's experience with optimising this?

---

**Edit:** The question was originally posted in 2011. There is now a very stable D7 release of [advagg](http://drupal.org/project/advagg).

Answer (score 12):

For D7, there's [Core Library](http://drupal.org/project/core_library) which has a learning mode that aggregates based on real-world statistics about your site.

If you want to brute-force everything into one giant aggregate, I've [written an article](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/drupal-7-taking-control-css-and-js-aggregation) with some sample code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_js_alter().
 */
function mymodule_js_alter(&$javascript) {
  uasort($javascript, 'drupal_sort_css_js');
  $i = 0;
  foreach ($javascript as $name => $script) {
    $javascript[$name]['weight'] = $i++;
    $javascript[$name]['group'] = JS_DEFAULT;
    $javascript[$name]['every_page'] = FALSE;
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_css_alter().
 */
function mymodule_css_alter(&$css) {
  uasort($css, 'drupal_sort_css_js');
  $i = 0;
  foreach ($css as $name => $style) {
    $css[$name]['weight'] = $i++;
    $css[$name]['group'] = CSS_DEFAULT;
    $css[$name]['every_page'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

[Drupal.org issue #1034208](http://drupal.org/node/1034208) also proposes relaxing the strict ordering requirements slightly.

Comment: The giant aggregate did not seem to produce the correct behaviour, it would indeed make 1 large CSS/JS file for page, but this file would change depending on the page you are on. This is obviously less than ideal.

Comment: Exactly right, if each page loads different JS files, then the aggregate will necessarily be different. You've just rediscovered the reason Drupal 7 splits files into functional groups (JS_LIBRARY, JS_DEFAULT, and JS_THEME).  With complex sites this is often more efficient than one giant file.

Comment: If there are 3 groups, how can there be 5 files loaded in the head? Why not never more than 3? Bundling everything in 1 file is apparently a horrible idea, but how to keep the JS files to a mimimum?

Comment: i have tried the code that mentioned here. Actually it creating two compressed js files for me. How can I make it one js file?

Comment: @DylanTack one of my website has problem with loading css fiels [http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/128649/drupal-7-website-layout-styling-breaks-all-a-sudden-random-how-to-debug-ther] and website address [http://living.md/] I was wandering where to put your code, and can i use your code along with advagg module ?

Answer (score 3):

AdvAgg D7 is being developed. Other options (quotes included are from their project pages):

- [UglifyJS](https://www.drupal.org/project/uglifyjs):

> ... allows on-the-fly minification of site JavaScript with uglify.js. The module relies on a web service (uglify.me) by default to do the minification so you do not need to do any pre-processing on your server to enjoy the benefits of minified JavaScript.

- [Speedy](https://www.drupal.org/project/speedy):

> ... designed to help speed up front end performance in a site. In this first release of the Speedy module it provides minified versions of core JavaScript files that are not already minified. For example, a minified version of drupal.js is provided while jquery.js (already minified) is not.

Comment: AdvAgg 7.x is now at its first RC. https://drupal.org/project/advagg Recommend using it